# HTML and CSS question: How do I format a table to use uneven rows in each column?

Tags: html, css, layout, graphics, formatting

To preface this, I have learnt HTML and CSS through looking at other people’s work to understand the basics of its use, so my understanding is fractured at best. I’m trying to design a table with different row spacing in each column, to imitate the layout of the picture below. So far, nothing I’ve tried even comes close to working. Thus, my question is **what elements should I use to recreate this effect, or even better, what code is out there that has a similar use?**

[Block layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbMra.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It’s not possible using table. You will have to either use multiple tables or else make the layout with divs.

Comment: Investigate CSS grid rather than try to use HTML tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a CSS grid rather than a table.

This snippet's grid has 15 rows (there are 3 big items and 5 smaller ones going down in columns) and 10 columns (the bigger items are shown as having two smaller items width).

The big items occupy 5 rows each and the smaller items occupy 3 rows each.

We also want the items to fill the grid in a columnar direction rather than filling the first row first etc (which is the default).

We put the last 3 bigger items into specific positions so as to ensure other items do not take that space. Everything else just fills the grid up as it goes along.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 33vw;
  background: pink;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.container>div {
  background: cyan;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.container>div:nth-child(1),
.container>div:nth-child(2),
.container>div:nth-child(3),
.container>div:nth-child(14),
.container>div:nth-child(15),
.container>div:nth-child(16),
.container>div:nth-child(35),
.container>div:nth-child(36),
.container>div:nth-child(37) {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 5;
}

.container>div:nth-child(35) {
  grid-column: 5 / span 2;
  grid-row: 11 / span 5;
}

.container>div:nth-child(36) {
  grid-column: 7 / span 2;
  grid-row: 11 / span 5;
}

.container>div:nth-child(37) {
  grid-column: 9 / span 2;
  grid-row: 11 / span 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
  <div>26</div>
  <div>27</div>
  <div>28</div>
  <div>29</div>
  <div>30</div>
  <div>31</div>
  <div>32</div>
  <div>33</div>
  <div>34</div>
  <div>35</div>
  <div>36</div>
  <div>37</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the attribute rowspan and colspan like this:

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Batch</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Computer Science</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Break</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```